# Revert file in Perforce P4V from a different computer

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a couple files checked out in Perforce on a different computer that I won't have access to until tomorrow. I received a request to revert them but I'm not sure how to do that from my home computer. I don't see an option and I can't find any results about this for the visual client. Is it even possible?

Comment: Unless you have the files locked, why would anyone care?  And note that reverting files from another machine will probably leave your client in a weird state (the file presumably would still have whatever changes you made but would no longer be open for edit).

Comment: @jamesdlin - Good question! I have no idea why anyone would care to be honest. But this is for a class I'm in and it was the teacher who requested it, so I didn't question it. Maybe he just wants to ensure no one will accidentally merge/update over the changes he was going to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a suitable solution for myself.

I opened P4V and navigated to my workspaces. I edited the one with the checked out files and changed the workspace root and host to be from my current computer. After applying that, I was able to revert them as I normally would from the P4V client.

Answer (score 1):

[p4 revert](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_revert.html) takes as an option the client name, i.e workspace name.

From `P4V>File> Open Command window here` and try :

```
p4 revert -C *yourotherworkspace* -c changelist //...
```

If this is not enough you might have to add some [global options](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html) settings like :

```
p4 -H remote_computer_name revert -C *yourotherworkspace* -c changelist //...
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I click "Open Command Window Here". I'm not sure why.